# How can Traditional Korean Music notation be input in Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, music

Hangul Word and Microsoft Word are capable of representing the Chinese characters necessary to represent traditional Korean music. **However, in Ubuntu/Linux I have always been baffled at how to accomplish this** whether in LibreOffice or some other software. Is there a way to input all the necessary characters in Ubuntu or a program that runs in Ubuntu.

First there is the font problem. Many True Type fonts available for the the Chinese character set do now contain all the glyphs necessary for representing the language according to fc-validate. Those that do have all the necessary glyphs still do not contain ALL the Chinese characters necessary to represent traditional Korean music. Ideally I should be able to type all these shown below. But there are holes which I have filled in with Hangul.

> 㑀太汰㳲 F
>
> 황黃潢㶂 Eflat
>
> 㒣應㶐㶝 D
>
> 㒇無潕㶃 Dflat
>
> 㑲南湳㵜 C
>
> 侇夷洟㴣 Cflat
>
> 임林淋임 Bflat
>
> 仲中중㴢 Aflat
>
> 고姑㴌고 G
>
> 俠夾浹협 Gflat

This represents all the notes in an in four octaves.

This website shows what I am trying to do (but in Korean). [JungKanBo](http://www.gugak.go.kr/site/homepage/menu/viewMenu?menuid=001003001001001002001)

Comment: hi! welcome to askubuntu! does korean have something like chinese for input like sogoupinyin? also could you edit your question to specify what is posing a problem? are you not fining the "insert character" or would you like to be able to input it with some sort of pinyin? would you mind using google-drive/word instead? I'm a big linux-head but I have to admit Libre office no longer really cuts it in this day and age.

Comment: The problem is twofold. The first problem is that not all the necessary characters are available as can be seen in the list above. Wherever there is Hangul it means the Hanja character was not available. Second, in the IME frequently used Hanja characters cannot be moved to the front of the queue. This leads to very slow input of music as a single not may require paging through 5 or 6 panels of characters each and every time. Hanja (Chinese characters) are entered by typing Korean (Hangul) and selecting the appropriate Hanja from a popup that may have several panels.

Comment: So by "representing traditional Korean music" you meant showing the song track name in a music playing app, the choice of words there was more than a little misleading, I thought you were talking about musical notation, this doesn not help with my question of there being pinyin or not? I guess what you most need is a font installed right?

Comment: In the traditional system of musical notation notes (pitches) are represented by Chinese characters. They are written top to bottom right to left in table format. This is a simplified explanation. This has nothing to do with music playing apps.

Comment: but why would you use libreoffice when there are top-notch free and available-on-linux apps for writing sheet music?

Comment: There are no linux apps I am aware of that can produce traditional Korean music notation.

Comment: you're probably right but i'll look into that anyways.